# Duplicate entries in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting duplicate posts in the SQL DB.
This is the code I am using to create the table and insert data into the DB..

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM '.$cname.' WHERE name='$itemname' and price='$price'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    if($count == 0){
                        //insert doesn't exist, continue
                        //insert sizes
                        $list = "";
                        $number = count($sizes);
                        $num = 0;
                        if($usesize == 'yes'){
                            $num = 1;
                            if($number > 0){
                                for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++){
                                    if(trim($_POST["size"][$i] != '')){
                                        if(empty($list)){
                                            $list = $_POST["size"][$i];
                                        }else{
                                            $list .= ",".$_POST["size"][$i];
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                echo $list;
                            }

                            $quantitylist = "";
                            $quantitynumber = count($quantity);
                            if($quantitynumber > 0){
                                for($a=0; $a<$quantitynumber; $a++){
                                    if(trim($_POST["quantity"][$a] != '')){
                                        if(empty($quantitylist)){
                                            $quantitylist = $_POST["quantity"][$a];
                                        }else{
                                            $quantitylist .= ",".$_POST["quantity"][$a];
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                echo $quantitylist;
                            }
                        }else{
                            $num = 0;
                        }

                        $colorlist = "";
                        $colornumber = count($colors);
                        $cnum = 0;
                        if($usecolors == 'yes'){
                            $cnum = 1;
                            if($colornumber > 0){
                                for($i=0; $i<$colornumber; $i++){
                                    if(trim($_POST["colors"][$i] != '')){
                                        if(empty($colorlist)){
                                            $colorlist = $_POST["colors"][$i];
                                        }else{
                                            $colorlist .= ":".$_POST["colors"][$i];
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                echo $colorlist;
                            }
                        }else{
                            $cnum = 0;
                        }

                        $query = "INSERT INTO ".$cname." (name, description, imgpath, price, sold, usesize, usecolors) VALUES ('$itemname', '$description', '$insertloc"."$name', '$price', '0', '$num', '$cnum')";
                        if(mysqli_query($db, $query)){
                            //inserted successfully
                            echo "Inserted successfully!";
                        }else{
                            $uploadOk = 0;
                            echo mysqli_error($db);
                        }

                        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'grampmkn_gramsandpops', 'Grams123', 'grampmkn_shop_quantity');
                        if($conn){
                            $query = "CREATE TABLE `".$itemname."` (
                                                    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                                    size varchar(500),
                                                    color varchar(500),
                                                    quantity int(100),
                                                    PRIMARY KEY(id),
                                                    UNIQUE(size)
                                                    );";
                            $array = explode(',', $list);

                            if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
                                mysqli_select_db($conn, $name);
                                $array = explode(',', $list);
                                foreach($array as $value){
                                    $arrays = explode(':', $colorlist);
                                    foreach($arrays as $values){
                                        $arrays1 = explode(',', $quantitylist);
                                        foreach($arrays1 as $values1){
                                            $query = "INSERT INTO `".$itemname."` (size, color, quantity) VALUES ('$value', '$values', '$values1')";
                                            if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
                                                echo "Successfully inserted data into grampmkn_shop_quantity!";
                                            }else{
                                                echo mysqli_error($conn);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                                echo "Could not create table";
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo "Could not connect to shop quantity database!";
                            echo mysqli_errno($conn);
                        }
                    }else{
                        //insert already exists
                        echo "Insert already exists!";
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                    }
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FPv7.png) from DB.

If I remove the nested loops, then how would I get all the data in the arrays to insert into the sql database.
I am only creating the table once, I am just inserting multiple times to get all the data into the db.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: At a glance I'd guess it';s something to do with the 4 levels of nested loops :( Can you perhaps pull some of them out and gather data separately to each other loop?

Comment: You can't expect people to guess what your data looks like.  Also -- why are you creating a table over and over in your script.  You create a table it doesn't go away.  That should be in a seperate script that you run once at setup time, not in the script that inserts data.

Comment: What is `$list`?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would gather data separately without a nested loop.

Comment: Honestly I'd forget this issue for now and spend some time refactoring your code. You have too many nested IFs and loops. You could rip the `else` out of the `if`s and instead return or somehow else continue the script based on an outcome. Even setting a variable would make the if in a separate contained if at the start and not cause all your entire code to be in nested elses. This all makes it hard for even you to read and fix issues as you cannot clearly see what is going on

Comment: Okay, I appreciate it. I will be going through and redoing it.
I still need to know how to fix my problem though.

Comment: Totally appreciate that, but trying to figure that out is a lot of work as the code is currently. You really will value from making it all tidier, but in the meantime, right after `foreach($arrays1 as $values1){` you insert, instead add the values to a new array (and don't insert) and when all the loops are done, dump out that array and see what you have. That is what will be being inserted into your DB